# Angular 4 get API excel

Tags: angular

I wired up an api call that when hit downloads an excel file. If I go directly to the URL with the correct params it gives me the excel. I am having trouble wiring this up to the front end to get the file. I believe this is the correct service call but I am not sure what to do on the component side.

**Service**

```
getViolationFile(mid: string, cp: string, d: string, pl: string) {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('mid', mid);
    params.set('cp', cp);
    params.set('d', d);
    params.set('pl', pl);

    let headers = new Headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    });

    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers,
      search: params
    });

    return this.http.get('Violations/Download?', options)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting incorrect accept type in headers

Keep in mind types. Have a look on documentation of `get`, and see how you can parametrize that, to watch over correct data type:
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get
In your case this would be `observe?: 'body'` and `responseType: 'blob'` from which you will need to recreate your excel file from binaries.

After this function invocation (i.e. calling `getViolationFile`) do you actually subscribe to it? Angular `http` returns cold observable, so nothing will actually happen untill you will not subscribe to it. It shall look something like that:

```
getViolationFile('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
.subscribe((res) => {
  /* Here you have access to response data */
})
```

I think question is missing some additional details. Do you get any answer or nothing is queried by the network?

Comment: ohhh that makes a little more sense. What would the headers need to be set to?

Comment: @AlexD its `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` but this is not the main reason why your app is not working

Comment: Okay, well any help would be appreciated

Comment: @AlexD, rest of my answer is still valid (i.e. do you subscribe to your observable?)